# ASIHTTPRequest addRequestHeader issue

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHttpRequest and make use GET method to send header to server. I call method addRequestHeader like this

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addRequestHeader:@"myHeader" value:@"abc"];
```

It's not working. But if I use NSMutableURLRequest to add header and request to server, it works.
I don't know anything wrong when calling addRequestHeader methods for ASIHTTPRequest library.
Have anyone seen this issue?

Comment: Please, for the love of all that's good, DO NOT USE `ASIHttpRequest`.

`AFNetworking`, `NSURLSession`, and goodness `NSURLConnection` all have modern APIs that will solve your problems without using an outdated and unsupported library like `ASIHTTPRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

Wow ok so, yeah if this is a new app, please do NOT use ASIHttpRequest. It has long been supplanted by the delightful [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

If this is an existing application, you really should work on a migration plan off ASI.

However, in an attempt to actually answer your question - that is the appropriate setup per the documentation, and is how I used to use it. My guess is something is broken under the covers and judging from a basic google request, there are issues with iOS 7 including memory leaks and requests just failing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via `NSURLRequest`

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.abc.com"]];
NSMutableURLRequest *mutableRequest = [request mutableCopy];
[mutableRequest addValue:@"AAA" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Hello-there"];
request = [mutableRequest copy];
NSLog(@"%@", request.allHTTPHeaderFields);
```

Hope this helps .. :)