# Setting header using ASIHTTPRequest or ASIFormDataRequest

Tags: ios, iphone, http-headers, asihttprequest, asiformdatarequest

I want to set header using ASI and I wrote the following code for it but it is not working. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

My code is:

```
     ASIHTTPRequest *headReq=[ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
     [headReq addRequestHeader:@"Authorization" value:encodedData];
```

Comment: I started researching a solution to your problem but a lot of what I'm seeing is [telling me you should be using AFNetworking or NSURLRequest instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827199/asihttprequest-addrequestheader-issue).

Comment: ASIHTTP is no longer supported or recommended by the developer, don't use it in new code. From the ASIHTTP site: "Please note that I am no longer working on this library - you may want to consider using something else for new projects. :)".